# Load a screenshot into a function as a bitmap without saving it as a file first

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

Basically my program takes a "sample" image from the user, then takes a screenshot of the entire user's screen, and then if it found that sample on the users screen, it returns the coordinates of it and moves the mouse there.

It works fine if I save the screenshot to a bitmap and compare the sample to a file, but when I try to call the screenshot directly into the function, it fails to find a match.

Any idea why?

First the code for the button click that triggers the comparison:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim clickhere As Point

    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)


    Dim src As New Bitmap(srcpath.Text)



    Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenshot.Size)
    g.Dispose()


    clickhere = BitmapExtension.Contains(screenshot, src)
    MsgBox(clickhere.ToString)
    Cursor.Position = clickhere
End Sub
```

And here is the function:

```
 Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
    Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

    Module BitmapExtension

        <Extension()>
        Public Function Contains(src As Bitmap, ByRef bmp As Bitmap) As Point
            '
            '-- Some logic pre-checks
            '
            If src Is Nothing OrElse bmp Is Nothing Then Return New Point(Integer.MinValue, Integer.MinValue)

            If src.Width < bmp.Width OrElse src.Height < bmp.Height Then
                Return New Point(Integer.MinValue, Integer.MinValue)
            End If
            '
            '-- Prepare optimizations
            '
            Dim sr As New Rectangle(0, 0, src.Width, src.Height)
            Dim br As New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height)

            Dim srcLock As BitmapData = src.LockBits(sr, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
            Dim bmpLock As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(br, Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)

            Dim sStride As Integer = srcLock.Stride
            Dim bStride As Integer = bmpLock.Stride

            Dim srcSize As Integer = sStride * src.Height
            Dim bmpSize As Integer = bStride * bmp.Height

            Dim srcBuff(srcSize) As Byte
            Dim bmpBuff(bmpSize) As Byte

            Marshal.Copy(srcLock.Scan0, srcBuff, 0, srcSize)
            Marshal.Copy(bmpLock.Scan0, bmpBuff, 0, bmpSize)

            ' we don't need to lock the image anymore as we have a local copy
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpLock)
            src.UnlockBits(srcLock)

            Return FindMatch(srcBuff, src.Width, src.Height, sStride, bmpBuff, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, bStride)

        End Function

        Private Function FindMatch(srcBuff() As Byte, srcWidth As Integer, srcHeight As Integer, srcStride As Integer,
        bmpBuff() As Byte, bmpWidth As Integer, bmpHeight As Integer, bmpStride As Integer) As Point
            For Y As Integer = 0 To srcHeight - bmpHeight - 1
                For x As Integer = 0 To srcWidth - bmpWidth - 1
                    If AllPixelsMatch(x, Y, srcBuff, srcStride, bmpBuff, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, bmpStride) Then
                        Return New Point(x, Y)
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            Return New Point(Integer.MinValue, Integer.MinValue)
        End Function

        Private Function AllPixelsMatch(X As Integer, Y As Integer, srcBuff() As Byte, srcStride As Integer,
          bmpBuff() As Byte, bmpWidth As Integer, bmpHeight As Integer, bmpStride As Integer) As Boolean
            For by As Integer = 0 To bmpHeight - 1
                For bx As Integer = 0 To bmpWidth - 1
                    Dim bmpIndex As Integer = by * bmpStride + bx * 4
                    Dim a As Byte = bmpBuff(bmpIndex + 3)
                    'If bmp pixel is not transparent, check if the colours are identical
                    If a > 0 T

hen
                    Dim srcX = X + bx
                    Dim srcY = Y + by
                    Dim srcIndex = srcY * srcStride + srcX * 4
                    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
                        'check if the r, g and b bytes match
                        If srcBuff(srcIndex + i) <> bmpBuff(bmpIndex + i) Then Return False
                    Next
                Else
                    'if bmp pixel is transparent, continue seeking.
                    Continue For
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Why do you take two screenshots? I don't think you need the `Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(...)` statement, nor the two lines after that. This could be your troubling statement.